# strange function definition in Scilab<->C interface

Tags: c, function, wrapper, scilab

I'am talking about this example of a Scilab<->C wrapper: http://www.scilab.org/doc/intro/node89.html.

The strange part is this one:

```
int intsfoubare(fname) 
 char *fname;
   {
     ....(some code)
   }
```

It is some kind of function defintion but I really don't understand what the char *fname is good for also just fname as parameter makes no sense to me.

Is someone able to explain this?

[start crying]
Scilabs documentation in general is a negative example but when it comes to the C-interface it's even worse.
[end crying]

Thanks!

Comment: Wow! In this day and age, they have this K&R style function! That is ummm...antique by today's standards, ANSI/ISO C became de-facto in 1989 which specified that function declarations include the parameter and its data type at the same time, i.e. int itsfoubare(char *fname) which is what most C compilers use. I am amazed at this, plus the french spelling for foobar or fubar which is the more accurate spelling! I like this question as it is unusual to see old K&R code lying around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking at is the K&R style of function declaration. It's approximately equivalent to `int intsfoubare(char *fname) { ... }`, but allows more somewhat more flexibility in calling the function. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/what-is-useful-about-this-c-syntax) for more details.

Comment: Yep thats the answer the linked post explains it very good, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Scilab, but I know French!

"foubare" sounds like French for "foobar". This could be a case of a dummy or test function some developer (accidentally?) left in place.

`fname` sounds like the name of a file name, passed in as a character pointer.

Maybe this will help a bit.

As for the way that `fname` is used: In the older, "classic" C language definition, it was (in fact still is) legal to put just the name of a passed parameter in the parentheses, and declare its type later. You don't see much of that any more, but it's not totally wrong either. Just pretend the parentheses say `(char *fname)` .

Answer (score 0):

That's the old style (before ANSI/ISO standardized C in 1989) definition of functions.
Nowadays with prototypes it is written (though the old style is still accepted) as

```
int intsfoubare(char *fname)
{
    ....(some code)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the Scilab documentation on this subject is now way better!

See: http://help.scilab.org/docs/current/en_US/api_scilab.html