# Why c functions can be defined this way?

Tags: c, syntax

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is useful about this C syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/what-is-useful-about-this-c-syntax)
>   [What is this strange function definition syntax in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016213/what-is-this-strange-function-definition-syntax-in-c)

```
static void
add_shopt_to_alist (opt, on_or_off)
     char *opt;
     int on_or_off;
{
...
}
```

What's the syntax for :

```
(opt, on_or_off)
         char *opt;
         int on_or_off;
```

?

Comment: This is an older (closer to the original) version of C known know as "K&R C": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K.26R_C

Comment: See [What is this strange function definition syntax in C?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016213/what-is-this-strange-function-definition-syntax-in-c).