# what is the weird usage in C language

Tags: c

these days i have been reading the dhcpd source code in which there are many such usage represented below,i don't understand what that is...

what happened when the `struct packet *packet;` between the param list and the `{` ?

```
int locate_network (packet)
struct packet *packet;
{
    struct iaddr ia;
    struct data_string data;
    struct subnet *subnet = (struct subnet *)0;
    struct option_cache *oc;

    if ((oc = lookup_option(&agent_universe, packet->options,
               RAI_LINK_SELECT)) == NULL)
    oc = lookup_option(&dhcp_universe, packet->options,
               DHO_SUBNET_SELECTION);
    //.........
}
```

Comment: The real question is what modern compiler can still handle old-style K&R function declarations. Is the code you're reading of historical interest only?

Comment: Other duplicates: [What weird C syntax is this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380599/what-weird-c-syntax-is-this), [What is this strange function definition syntax in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3016213), [C statement between function declaration and curly brace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9834916), [C variable declarations after function heading in definition](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2633776), [Alternate C syntax for function declaration use cases](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1630631), [Why c functions can be defined this way?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4191649)

Comment: no its not for historical interest only,i want to know how the dhcp server works @CodyGray

Answer (score 4):

That's the older K&R style of function declaration, superceded by the ANSI style you are probably more familiar with. See also [Function declaration: K&R vs ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-kr-vs-ansi)