# Extract function names only and their comments from C code

Tags: c, perl, sed, awk, comments

I want to extract comments and want to know from which functions they are. I have lots of such C files as below:

**With input:**

```
void main()
{
    //sdgs
    call A;
    /*
    sdfgs
    dfhdfh
    */
    call b;
    some code;
}

/* this function adds
 something */
int add()
{
    //sgsd
    some code;
    //more comments
    some code;
}
```

**Output should be:**

```
void main()
{
    //sdgs

    /*
    sdfgs
    dfhdfh
    */

}

/* this function adds
 something */
int add()
{
    //sgsd

    //more comments

}
```

Input code is neatly formatted and 'function code' starts after `{` at next line.
Basically, I just need to know which 'comment' is from which function. Also it should include any other comments above function name or elsewhere. **Note: this is different as function names at top level should be there.**

To simplify my requirements:

1. Print all comments
2. Detect a block containing `(` on the first line, with a single line containing only `{` at first column after one to three lines and print the lines immediately above.

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible with regular expressions, you need to write a little C parser.

Why?

First there are macro's that need to be substituted first. Second because function defintions are kind of "hard" to put in a regular expression. Some legal function definitions:

```
int f() {}
const int f() {}
const char* f(int);
void f(double t);
void f(t,a) int t; int (*a)(float, char, char) {}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is: "void f(t,a) int t;" doing?

Comment: @w00te: It declares a function returning nothing (void) that takes two parameters, an `int` called `t` and a pointer to a function taking a `float, char, char` as arguments and returning an `int` called `a`. I did make a (now edited) mistake, I forgot the return type of the function pointer. Also, this is a combination of old-style function declarations and function pointers.

Comment: I though the 3rd and 4th examples would be a valid declaration, but not definition.

Comment: @sidyll: Sure, but you can easily replace the semicolon with brackets to make them definitions, it was just an example.

Comment: ok, if line x has { at first column and that's the only thing in that line, then x-l has function name end with ) and goes up till line number (x minus --) till start of (  <==is it still not possible?

Comment: Although perl regexes can more than "usual" regular expressions (type-3 language) writing a parser is the best way to do that as it gets tricky, when `"` and `'` come into play. You can still use regexes for the lexing part though.

Comment: I'm still confused, haha.  void f(t,a) int t; - how can it take int t as a parameter when int t is outside the parenthesis?  And I'm definitely not arguing, I just wanted to understand it in case I saw it again. :)

Comment: my simplified requirements: 1. print all comments 2. print next lines if it contains '('  & after 1, or 2 or 3 lines, there is line containing only { at first column

Comment: @w00te: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016213/what-is-this-strange-function-definition-syntax-in-c

Comment: Wow, that's what I get for starting in the C#/C++ era instead of the C era, haha.  I've been through a thousand books and never even ran into that.  Anyway, thanks for the help, +1! :)

Comment: @nightcracker not quite, you'd need to name the parameter in the 3rd example :-) just a comment though

Answer (score 2):

It is perhaps not doable in a very general sense (e.g. because functions could be defined by what is apparently a macro invocation).

But if you don't care about perfection, you might make a simple lexer & parser which nearly does the job (on input code which is not too contrived).

I'm not sure it is useful. You should explain what you really want to achieve.

Comment: function name is not in defined thru macro or any other complex way. it's function like unsigned int func_data( arg one, agrg two)
{

Answer (score 0):

you want to print only comments and function defintions from a well formated file. In my opinion this specific task is doable without a proper parser.

Try:

comments.awk:

```
/^(int|void|{|}|etc.)/{print $0;next}
/\/\*/,/\*\//{print $0;next}
/\s*\/\//{print $0;next}
```

call with:

```
awk -f comments.awk file1
```

Comment: but it print function name containing int or void. that's not what i want. i think awk/sed being line processor--it cannot be done unless one can see 3 or 4 lines ahead. thanks for ur help though