# Detecting amount of shifts in Caesar Cipher? in C

Tags: c, shift, caesar-cipher

I was wondering how in a Caesar cipher one would detect the amount of shifts in a encrypted text file that is read from the program and then display that certain amount?
Thank you!
EDIT**
I also read in a smallDictionary file for argv[2].
The rotate function:

```
  int rotate(int c, int n){
if (n == 0) return c;
int nRot = abs(n) % (RANGECHAR + 1);
if(n > 0)
return rotatePlus(c + nRot);
else
return rotateMinus(c - nRot);
}





int main( int argc, char *argv[]){

FILE *fp = stdin;  // defaults
int  n = 13;
int shift;
int i = 0;
// process command line
switch(argc) {
case 2: // only have n, assumed input from stdin
n = atoi(argv[1]);
break;
case 3: // have n and input file 
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // should check for problems
n  = atoi(argv[2]);
break;
default:
fp = stdin;
n  = 13;
}
// rotate text
int c;
while( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
if(!isspace(c)){
 c= rotate(c,n);

}
i++;
    printf("%c", c);
}

fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Get a dictionary file with a bulk of words in a specific language and keep shifting until you find a real word?

Comment: define real word, [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Comment: Statistical analysis ?

Comment: @GrawCube I have a dictionary file with the words that I use with a command line arguement, but I was wondering how I can detect how many times the decrypted word has to be shifted until it is a word. For example if I open a text file with "ifmmp" then i use the decrypter it would read the file and then find out that it was actually "hello" then returning the amount of shifts which would be 1.

Comment: @self For example I have a smallDictionary file with a couple thousand words from a-zA-z. I use this with an arguement that the program uses. For example: ./decrypter xFile smallDictionary and x would be the amount of shifts detected in the encrypted file.

Answer (score 3):

You would need distribution data for the language (presumably English) which could come in a form of an array `int lang_distribution[26]`. Then you would have to make an another array, like `int doc_distribution[26]` which would be filled with the data taken from your text. Both of them should be normalized so that they represent a relative occurrence of characters.

The next step would be comprised of shifting the `doc_distribution` by an integer from `0` to `25` and for every shift the program should measure the sum of `abs(lang_distribution[x] - doc_distribution[x])` where `x belongs to <0,25>`. The shift with the lowest sum of differences is your code for the cipher. All this could by implemented by two nested `for()` elements. The tricky part could be indexing in the loops but you could probably achieve the proper result by using modulo `%` operator.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how I could implement that. So far I can display the text file in its encrypted form. Ill show my code in my post.

Comment: First step would be making all of the characters lower case and checking whether you got only alphanumeric characters. Here some info about changing the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708793/c-convert-an-uppercase-letter-to-lowercase . As for the checking for alpha, one way of doing that would be comparing the `c` in the `while()` loop with 'a' and 'z'. Reason for the is that the a-z characters in ASCII come after themselves.

Comment: Ive managed to only add a lowercased letter into the message. How do I make it so it just reads each character makes it lowercase instead of a certain letter?