# Different ways to declare main in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternate C syntax for function declaration use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/alternate-c-syntax-for-function-declaration-use-cases)

I see this very different definition of `main()` in an old C-program. (It **does compile**, with gcc)

```
main(argc, argv)
   int argc;
   char *argv[]; 
   {
   ...
   ...

   }
```

What kind of variables are being declared and why are they being done before the beginning of the function brace?

Comment: Didn't quite know how to search for that.

Comment: Not voting to close because if anything this one should be kept as it has a more searchable, specific title.

Comment: @djechlin: Only because the other title is crap. We should adapt this title into that question and close this one as a dup.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - *shrug*.  done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is old style of function definition in C. This non-prototype style is marked as obsolescent in the C Standard and should not be used.

And omitting the return type (implicitly `int`) is no longer permitted in C.

Answer (score 1):

It implicitly returns `int` per the C spec (although per other answers in this and the linked question this was obsoleted in C99?), as is the case with functions with undeclared return type.

This is an old style of declaration, it comes from Fortran.

```
main(argc, argv)
   int argc;
   char *argv[];
```

Tells you exactly what you'd expect - that argc is an `int` and `argv` is an arryay of `char *`.

Comment: Are you sure the implicit return type is true for ISO C? C99 5.1.2.2.1/1 suggests not; 6.7.2/2 says it explicitly, by my interpretation.

Comment: Not sure, edited accordingly.

Comment: Would be interested to see a citation from some standard about the implicit return.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a K&R-style definition. You basically just list the parameters and declare them between the closing argument bracket and the opening curly bracket.

Answer (score 1):

That's an old KnR C style, pre 1989 C (non-standard). It was a way to pass arguments to functions.. not only with main() that was with every other function as well.

For example:

```
void non_main(argx, argy)
int argx,argy;
{
   /*do something here*/
}
```

Comment: It's still standard, even in the 2011 ISO C standard, but it's obsolescent and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply an alternative way of specifying the types of the arguments to `main`. It is exactly equivalent to `main(int argc, char *argv[])`. This is known as K&R style, as it's the original style used in the original C compiler and K&R books. It is considered obsolete; it is not compatible with C++. There's a GCC option to warn about it, `-Wold-style-definition`, but you will still see it in some old code.

Comment: It is not equivalent. For example if you have a function call `main(a, b)` and `a` is an object of type `double`, `a` will not be converted to `int` as with prototype definition.

Comment: @ouah Thanks for the clarification; I hadn't thought of that.