# How do i go from one function (main) to another without finishing main?(in C)

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

I am a beginner in C and there is one problem i can't seem to solve. I want to go from main() for example, to another function with a line or two of code. I have searched the Internet and nothing has answered this specific question, or so it seems to my amateur eyes. For example, i want to do this:

```
int main(void){
/*here i need a line of code that will make the program run FunctionToCall*/

}
int FunctiontoCall(void){
printf ("you went to this function! congratulations!\n");

}
```

I hope that helps sorry for the unclear question!

Comment: Please elaborate your problem

Comment: Post code to give us details.

Comment: can you just invoke the other function?

Comment: just give a prototype of it before defining main() and then you'll be able to call your function, what errors and warning you're getting

Comment: `void main() { other_function(); }`

Comment: @AlexFarber `int main(void) { other_function(); }`

Comment: @AlexFarber: `void main()` is incorrect (except possibly for some embedded systems). The correct definition is `int main(void)`. If you have a book or tutorial that tells you to use `void main()`, get a better one; it was written by someone who doesn't know the C language very well.

Comment: @Keith Thompson - thanks, I will by a better C book ASAP!

Comment: @Jens: please add `return 0;` to your function.

Comment: I presume you're using a book or tutorial. Keep reading; you'll see examples of function calls.

Comment: @AlexFarber: `return 0;` is optional in `main`; starting with C99, reaching the closing `}` of the `main` function is equivalent to `return 0;`. (This applies only to `main`.)

Comment: @AlexFarber: What book are you using?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Visual Basic6 For Dummies. I found another books so complicated...

Comment: @Mahesh: You mean C book, not C++ book, right?

Comment: @AlexFarber: Seriously, if you have a C book that says to use `void main()`, which book is it? I'd like to be able to warn people away from it.

Comment: @Keith Thomson....Yeah,c book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you in understanding how a method call works[image]

So when you call a method x from method y control from x passes to y and return back to x when a return statement/last statement of the called method is encountered

Comment: @user2651382 what OS are you using / any IDE?? is console appearing if you are working on windows??

Comment: If you're going to include code in your answer, please copy-and-paste it as formatted text. Your screenshot is very difficult to read.

Comment: @KeithThompson sure will keep a check of it from now on :)

Answer (score 2):

Just call the function you want to go to.

For example:

```
void functionToCall(int x, int y, int z);

int main() {
   //some code...
   functionToCall(x, y, z);
   //more code...
}

void functionToCall(int x, int y, int z) {
   //more code...
}
```

Comment: `function(x,y,z);` is not valid C; the types are missing. Don't confuse a beginner with sloppy snippets...

Comment: Yes, both the return type and the parameter types are missing.

Comment: I know. The types are arbitrary. I just put them in to give an example of parameters. I didn't want to add types to avoid confusion.

Comment: Answering a question with incorrect code which won't compile is more likely to lead to confusion than avoid it, especially for someone who apparently doesn't know how to call functions at all.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: Even K&R C required you to declare the types of your parameters.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/alternate-c-syntax-for-function-declaration-use-cases), the parameter type specifiers are optional in pre-C99 code, and are assumed `int`

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: `functionToCall(x, y, z) { /* code ... */ }` is a valid function definition in (pre-ANSI) K&R C; the parameters and the function result are implicitly of type `int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: If you want them to be `int`s, then yes, you're right.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen While K&R allows implicit int, it doesn't allow non-empty parameter lists in a function declaration, IIRC.

Comment: @Jens: Not in a declaration, but a K&R function definition includes a list of parameter names.

Comment: A simpler solution is to put the definition of `functionToCall` above the definition of `main`; then no separate declaration is needed.