# C and defining a function prototype with no parameters

Tags: c++, c

This question is an offshoot of [`f(void)` meaning no parameters in C++11 or C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376783/fvoid-meaning-no-paramters-in-c11-or-c)

Several have answered that question and opined that in C, the meaning of the function prototype

```
void func ()
```

is that func is a function returning nothing (void) and whose parameters are unknown at this time.

Further they have opined that one could make this declaration and then invoke the function with some arguments such as:

```
func (1, 2, 3);
```

So, I did this, I made a test to verify that this works and I'm not surprised that it does.

Here is func.c, which contains `main()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void func ();

int main (int ac, char ** av)
{
  func (1, 2, 3);

  return 0;
}
```

And here is func1.c which contains the function `func()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func (int a, int b, int c)
{
  printf ( "%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c );
}
```

And here are my question(s)

**Question 1:**

When I run this program, I get, as expected the output 1, 2, 3.
Is this a safe way to write code; i.e. can one assume that the ABI will reliably ensure that the invocation of `func()` in `main()` will put the three parameters in the right places (registers, stack, whatever) for `func()` to find them?

**Question 2:**

If the answer to 1 above is that it is a safe thing to do, then does your answer change if `func()` is implemented in some language other than C?

Comment: Even if it were safe in C (I would say not, for obvious reasons), it would be illegal in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza AFAIK it's safe in C. `1, 2, 3` are literals of type `int` - when you invoke `foo(1, 2, 3)`, the not-known-until prototype is assumed to be `void (int, int, int)`.

Comment: Remember that in C there is no function overloading. A big difference between C and C++.

Comment: Using empty parameter lists in function prototypes in `C` cannot, for this very reason, provide a safe ABI. Don't use that, unless your function is prepared to take *any type and number or arguments*.

Comment: It's not "safe" in the sense that the compiler can not check your function calls for you to see if the arguments match the prototype.

Comment: @H2CO3 OK, but what happens if I call it with `foo(1,2,"Hello", 3.14);`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Undefined behavior.

Comment: @Walter Empty argument lists are **not** usable for specifying variable arguments.

Comment: @H2CO3 OK, that is what I meant by it not being safe. I should have stated that more clearly.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah, OK. Let's agree that it works if invoked only with the correct number and type of arguments, and it doesn't otherwise.

Comment: @H2CO3 Or rather, it's an obsolete feature, and a good, modern C++ will warn if you try to use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you asking about C or about C++?

C did not originally have function prototypes.  You'd write:

```
extern void func();
```

and then define it:

```
void func( a, b, c )
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
{
    //  ...
}
```

C++ added function prototypes, and made the above illegal.  And
the declaration:

```
extern void func();
```

declared a function which had no parameters; calling it with
arguments was an error, as was defining it with arguments.

C then added function prototypes from C++.  But to avoid
breaking existing code, it didn't require them, and treated

```
extern void func();
```

as before: a function taking an unknown number and types of
parameters.  So it also added:

```
extern void func(void);
```

as a special way of saying that the function doesn't take any
parameters.  C++ then added this special case for reasons of
C compatibility.

The general rule, in C++, is to just write:

```
extern void func();
```

The only time you'd use the form with `void` is in a header that
had to be compatible with both languages.  In C, of course, this
form doesn't do what you want, so you have to add the `void`.
(For now.  From what I understand, C has deprecated the older
forms, and so could, in the future, behave exactly like C++ in
this respect.)

### EDIT:

Having looked it up.  From the C11 standard, §6.11.6:

> The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not
>   prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent
>   feature.

Don't do it in C.

Comment: Quoting the standard is an automatic +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Q1. If the arguments are the right type, then MAYBE it will work (it probably will). But try `func(1.2, "blah");` and see what that does - it may "work" in the sense that it doesn't crash - it will certainly compile.

Q2. See answer to Q1. It is not at all safe.