# how to repeat a c program from the beginning and clean the screen and 1st input values?

Tags: c, loops, console-application

i m new in programing.
i've written a simple program.
i want to repeat the program again and again and it can only exit when user wants to exit.
here is my program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    char ch;
    int num1, num2, a, m, s, choice;
    float d;
    printf("\nEnter The First Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("\nEnter The Second Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    a=num1+num2;
    m=num1*num2;
    s=num1-num2;
    d=(float)(num1/num2);
    printf("\nEnter Your Choice \nFor Addition Type A \nFor Multipication Type M \nFor Division Type D \nFor Substraction Type S : ");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    switch(ch)
        {
            case 'A': printf("\nThe Addition Of The Number Is= %d", a);
                break;
            case 'M': printf("\nThe Multipication Of The Numbers Is= %d", m);
                break;
            case 'S': printf("\nThe Substraction Of THe Numbers Is= %d", s);
                break;
            case 'D': printf("\nThe Division Of The Two Numbers Is= %f", d);
                break;
            default : printf("\nInvalid Entry");
                break;
        }
    printf("\nPress Any Key To Exit");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the output

"**Enter The First Number: 10**

**Enter The Second Number: 10**

**Enter Your Choice**

**For Addition Type A**

**For Multipication Type M**

**For Division Type D**

**For Substraction Type S : A**

**The Addition Of The Number Is= 20**

**Press Any Key To Exit**"

I want a line before the line **Press Any Key To Exit**

"**If You Want To Calculate Again Press Y**

**or**

**Press Any Key To Exit**"

when press **Y** then the program should start from the beginning.

How can i do this???

Comment: Have you heard about [goto](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_goto_statement.htm) in `C`?

Comment: no. can you explain? plz

Comment: see the link in my comment. Also `while..loop` is another option.

Comment: @Jayesh While goto is a correct solution, I would like to point out the problems it has: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto#Criticism

Comment: @MaxySpark `main()` is not a valid declaration of the main function (according to the C standard), it should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. This also goes for C++ (with the minor difference that you don't use `void` as the argument), see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main

Comment: @MaxySpark You should be careful with `(float)(num1 / num2)`. When `num2 == 0` this will cause a division by zero error.

Comment: @MaxySpark `conio.h` only works on MS-DOS and Windows, it is a legacy header file. I wouldn't use it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Comment: @MaxySpark It wouldn't clear the screen at all (that's pointless and only means that the user can't see his previous input, also there is no standard way to clear the "screen"/virtual terminal). You can use `getchar()` (from `stdio.h`)  instead of `getch()` (from `conio.h`).

Comment: @Jens Mühlenhoff what will happen if i write 'int main()'. Is it correct for **C**?

Comment: @MaxySpark It is not correct for `C`, see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376783/fvoid-meaning-no-paramters-in-c11-or-c

Comment: @MaxySpark I wrote an answer which tries to address these issues and more.

Comment: The cool way to do this is with recursion. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wrap the code inside a `do{} while()` ?

```
char answer;
do{
printf("\nEnter The First Number: ");
scanf("%d", &num1);
printf("\nEnter The Second Number: ");
scanf("%d", &num2);
a=num1+num2;
m=num1*num2;
s=num1-num2;
d=(float)(num1/num2);
printf("\nEnter Your Choice \nFor Addition Type A \nFor Multipication Type M \nFor Division Type D \nFor Substraction Type S : ");
scanf(" %c", &ch);
switch(ch)
    {
        case 'A': printf("\nThe Addition Of The Number Is= %d", a);
            break;
        case 'M': printf("\nThe Multipication Of The Numbers Is= %d", m);
            break;
        case 'S': printf("\nThe Substraction Of THe Numbers Is= %d", s);
            break;
        case 'D': printf("\nThe Division Of The Two Numbers Is= %f", d);
            break;
        default : printf("\nInvalid Entry");
            break;
    }
printf("\nPress Y to continue. Press any Key To Exit");
scanf(" %c",&answer); // dont forget type &
}
while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');
```

Declare a variable, let's say answer, which will store the user answer when you ask for "Press Y to continue. Press any Key To Exit". Check to see what value has that variable. If is 'y' or 'Y', the loop will repeat. If the user pressed other key, the loop is over.

Comment: can you explain how to write the condition after while. please

Comment: 1) There is no "Do" in C (maybe you meant "do" ?) 2) there should be a semicolon after the while(condition): `while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');`

Comment: @MaxySpark: use clrscr(); See http://priyankmaniar.hubpages.com/hub/Explaining---clrscr--and-getch-in-C

Comment: `clrscr()` is a non-standard function, in the non-standard `conio.h` header. There *is* no general way to "clear the screen" in C. One way is to print lots of empty lines (and you don't know how many); another way is to use `ncurses`, which is available for lots of platforms; or find out if the OP's terminal supports Terminal Escape codes, and use those.

Comment: @MaxySpark: *that* you should type in Google.

Comment: I mean how can i use **ncurses** here?

Comment: @MaxySpark: not surprisingly, the command is called [`clear()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/curs_clear). As you are "new in programing", looking up how to install ncurses on your system and then use it is a pretty good exercise.

Answer (score 2):

I would move the calculation stuff in it's own function and then use `while()` in `main`.

I have tried to fix other problems as well (this solution only uses standard C functions).

```
#include <stdio.h> // puts, printf, fprintf, scanf, getchar, stderr, EOF
#include <stdlib.h> // exit, EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <ctype.h> // toupper

char fail_on_eof (int c)
{
    if (c == EOF)
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    // In case of fail_on_eof (scanf (...)) the return value of this this
    // function is not useful
    // scanf () returns the number of chars read or EOF
    // getchar () returns a char or EOF
    return (char) c;
}

void skip_to_next_line (void)
{
    char c;
    do
    {
        c = fail_on_eof (getchar ());
    } while (c != '\n');
}

char read_upcase_char_line (char* prompt)
{
    char c;
    printf ("%s ", prompt);
    c = fail_on_eof (toupper (getchar ()));
    skip_to_next_line ();
    return c;
}

int read_num_line (char* prompt)
{
    int num;
    printf ("%s ", prompt);
    fail_on_eof (scanf ("%d", &num));
    skip_to_next_line ();
    return num;
}

int calculate (void)
{
    char choice;
    int num1, num2, cont;
    num1 = read_num_line ("Enter the first number:");
    num2 = read_num_line ("Enter the second number:");
    puts("A - addition");
    puts("S - subtraction");
    puts("M - multiplication");
    puts("D - division");
    choice = read_upcase_char_line ("[ASMD]?");
    puts("");
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 'A':
            printf("%d + %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
            break;
        case 'S':
            printf("%d - %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 - num2);
            break;
        case 'M':
            printf("%d * %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 * num2);
            break;
        case 'D':
            if (num2 == 0)
                // Better use stderr for error messages
                fprintf(stderr, "The divisor can not be zero");
            else
            {
                printf("%d / %d = %f", num1, num2, (double)num1 / num2);
            }
            break;
        default :
            // Better use stderr for error messages
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid entry");
            break;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (;;)
    {
      cont = read_upcase_char_line ("Continue [YN]?");
      if (cont == 'Y')
          return -1;
      else if (cont == 'N')
          return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    while (calculate ());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; // Use this constant to avoid platform specific issues with the return code
}
```

Comment: I m new in programming. So i don't know about #include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>. Thats why your answer is little bit tough for me. :(

Comment: @MaxySpark You can look everthing up, for the different headers and there meaning see here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library

Comment: @MaxySpark Yes, I put some advanced methods in there, but I would advice you to study this solution as it contains some best practices and avoids some errors. You can ask, if you don't understand something.

Comment: @MaxySpark BTW: `stdbool.h` was uneccessary, I removed it. I also wrote which functions are imported from which headers. Maybe that helps.

Comment: thanx. tell me about **fprintf** **stderr** and **toupper**

Comment: @MaxySpark There are two default file handles called `stdout` and `stderr`, when you use `printf` the output goes to `stdout`. You can do the same with `fprintf(stdout, ...)`. Both streams are printed to the console by default, but you can redirect them. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stderr/

Comment: @MaxySpark `toupper` will convert lower case characters to upper case characters. So the program can use `a` as well as `A` which is more pleasing for the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), which is often used in more functional oriented programming languages.

Pseudo-code:

```
myfunction = do 
    ...
    b <- somethingtodo
    ...
    if b
      then myfunction 
      else return ()
```

Relative to [Jens's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25833196/1188670), it would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
    char choice;
    int num1, num2, cont;
    printf("Enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    getchar ();
    printf("Enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    getchar ();
    printf("A - addition\n");
    printf("S - subtraction\n");
    printf("M - multiplication\n");
    printf("D - division\n");
    printf("[ASMD]? ");
    choice = (char)toupper(getchar());
    getchar (); 
    printf("\n");
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 'A':
            printf("%d + %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
            break;
        case 'S':
            printf("%d - %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 - num2);
            break;
        case 'M':
            printf("%d * %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 * num2);
            break;
        case 'D':
            if (num2 == 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "The divisor can not be zero");
            else
            {
                printf("%d / %d = %f", num1, num2, (double)num1 / num2);
            }
            break;
        default :
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid entry");
            break;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (;;)
    {
      printf("Continue [YN]? ");
      cont = toupper(getchar());
      getchar ();
      if (cont == 'Y')
          return main(); // the difference.
      else if (cont == 'N')
          return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```