# VBA Debug Print producing unexpected and seemingly random output

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Can anyone shed some light on this.  In MS Word VBA I have a trivial Sub that produces rather unexpected results. [Edit: this issue has been reproduced on several different installations of MS Word but so far only Win10]

Repro Environments:

- Win10, Word 2010 (32-bit) PC
- Win10, Word 2010 (32-bit) VM-Azure
- Win10, Word 2016 (32-bit) PC
- Win10, Word 2010 (64-bit) VM-Azure
- Win10, Word 2016 365 @VincentG
- Win10, Word 2007 (32 bit) @Ambie
- Win10(64), Word XP @ThunderFrame
- Win10(64), Excel XP @ThunderFrame
- Win8.1(64), Word 2013 @miroxlav    (first repro outside of Win10)
- Win8.1(64), Office 2016 (32) @GSerg
- Win10(64), Word 2007 (x86) @PartricK
- Win10(64), Excel 2007 (x86) @PartricK

But no repro in:

- Win7 (64), Word 2007 (32-bit) VM Azure
- Win7 (64), Word 2010 (32?) @JohnColeman
- Win7 (64), Word 2007 (32) @Slai
- Win7 (64), Word 2003 (32) @GSerg
- WinXP (32), Word 2010 (32) @GSerg
- Win7 (64), Office 2010 (32)

Steps to reproduce:
Open new Word document
Open IDE (Alt + F11)
Enter this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100
Debug.Print vbCr
Next
End Sub
```

Run the test Sub.

My output varies each time the loop is run:

```
]Œ[p^"î;{Ñ[

]Œ[p^"î;{Ñ[

\ÒZžUÖè;qÑZ
```

or

```
ÿÿ

þþ@øø”¶(3

ÿÿ
```

or

```
>O

>O

>O
```

or

```
p

G   P‚j Ž¶&3@

p
```

Originally I thought I could recognize some content from my document, but now I get similar results for a blank document with nothing else open in Word.

It was quite disconcerting until I reproduced in the other Word installations, now its more of a distraction & puzzlement.

Any ideas about what's going on?

Comment: BTW: Effect seems to become more pronounced the more times the loop is run, although that might just be my imagination.

Comment: Interesting. I can't replicate (with Word 2010 on 64-bit Windows 7).

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm jealous what's your environment? (wow that was quick)

Comment: I was in the process of adding the environment when you asked about it. I'm the one that is jealous. My IDE seems boring in comparison :)

Comment: @JohnColeman I have just tried in Win 7 (64), Word 7 (32) and can report the result was satisfyingly boring...  seems like a Windows issue?

Comment: Sounds like a Windows issue. If I had to guess, it probably has something to do with Window's move towards a Unicode world. Exactly how, I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - mate... first thing I did was disable RD!  But, it has been repo'd on 3 different machines....  Happy to say RD was innocent :-D

Comment: any common add-in? seems like they might share some common corrupted component. You can also try `Debug.Print VBA.vbCr` just in case

Comment: @Slai Thanks for your interest. No. No common addins; in fact for the most part the VMs are basically clean machines that I use for testing.  As per comment above I disabled RD (RubberDuck for VBA) and a few other VBA IDE addins but that was on my main PC.  I also rebooted and problem persisted.

Comment: @Slai Good idea, tried VBA.vbCr and got the same result - but this time on a new VM: Win10, Word10 (64-bit)

Comment: Tried on Office 2016 365, Windows 10, got some `8(äBwAjc` as a result.

Comment: Tried `Debug.Print Chr(13)` with the same result, but `Debug.Print Chr$(13)`is working fine?

Comment: @VincentG - nice suggestion.  I just tried Chr$(13) and I still get the junk... :-/

Comment: I'm Windows 10 Word 2007 (32 bit) and I get  `eeeeee  ¥üVe.` amongst a whole load of other junk. Seeing as `Debug.Print vbCrLF` works fine, I'd be interested to know what happens on a genuine Mac OS..

Comment: can't reproduce on Win 7 (64), Word 2007 (32), so I blame it on the VBA 7. I even tried changing to different mono-space fonts.

Comment: @Ambie - thanks for sharing :-)  I've a mate with Mac OS so might hit him up for a test...

Comment: @Slai - I *think* a pattern is emerging... and Win10 is strongly implicated!

Comment: No-repro: Win7 (64), Word 2003 (32); Win 8.1 (64), Word 2016 (32); WinXP (32), Word 2010 (32).

Comment: @GSerg LOL WinXP - love it! Thanks will update :-)

Comment: Win 10 (64), Word XP is a repro but different characters, and different characters *each* time. Win 10 (64) Excel XP is a repro, but all lines show *only* `½s`, or *only* `½s` and `V`, or sometimes no repro.

Comment: @ThunderFrame I'm getting different characters each time I run this, I'll make this more clear...  thanks for confirming. Really looks like a Win10 thing

Comment: Interesting, if I use `Debug.Print vbCr;` there is no repro. If I use `Debug.Print vbCr; vbCr`, then *many* but not *all* outputs are `v` or `Cr`, which suggests a size, offset or null-terminator is out of whack.

Comment: @ThunderFrame I just tried `debug.print vbcr;` and got this: `$à.ª$†¶3@ˆ`  but the output was MUCH cleaner than before... only a little bit of junk

Comment: @GSerg - Repro: Win8.1 (64) Word 2013. Output garbage randomly varies if run multiple times.

Comment: With a Win10x64 (En) + Office 2007 (x86), both Word and Excel do reproduce similar symptom, however not all lines are gibberish, and sometimes it prints a few characters of my code. But if `Debug.Print i & vbCr`, it's clean! Temporary solution is to use `vbLf` or `vbCrLf` instead, they don't reproduce this symptom.

Comment: @GSerg - I'm unsure which is more desperate: using Office 2010 in Windows XP, or Office XP in Windows 10. ;-)

Comment: I stand corrected. Repro on Win 8.1 (64), Office 2016 (32). It just happened so that it looked normal when I tried it a couple of times. Tried five times in a row and it happened. And then it started happening easier (happens straight away after restarting Word/Excel).

Comment: @GSerg awww man you had me all excited... how sad is that?  will amend [oh you did, thanks :-)]

Comment: I will only use `vbNewLine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer, but here's a p-code dump of the word doc in .doc format:

Looks like the vbCr isn't corrupted

```
_VBA_PROJECT parsing done.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Module streams:
Macros/VBA/ThisDocument - 932 bytes
Macros/VBA/Module1 - 1478 bytes
Line #0:
        Option  (Explicit)
Line #1:
Line #2:
        FuncDefn (Sub test())
Line #3:
        Dim
        VarDefn i (As Integer)
Line #4:
        StartForVariable
        Ld i
        EndForVariable
        LitDI2 0x0001
        LitDI2 0x0064
        For
Line #5:
        Debug
        PrintObj
        Ld vbCr
        PrintItemNL
Line #6:
        StartForVariable
        Next
Line #7:
        EndSub
```

Comment: I know this 'not an answer' but it is the answer that showed me the most new stuff - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@Comintern and I have long speculated that the Immediate Window is in fact a pipe, or a conduit for `stdIn`/`stdOut`.

If we work on that basis, then this answer has some insights:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25843879/5757159

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character.
>
> **Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing conventions for representing text in the host environment.**

So it seems that Windows 10, *might* be getting something wrong when it processes the streams?

The workaround is to ensure that `Debug.Print` statements never end in `vbCr`, `Chr(10)` or `Chr$(10)`

Comment: I'll take a look, did a few more tests:
`Debug.Print vbCr & " "`  is clean
`Debug.Print vbCr & Chr$(10)` is clean
`Debug.Print Chr$(10)` is clean
`Debug.Print vbCr & ""`  is dirty
`Debug.Print vbCr & vbNullString`  is dirty
`Debug.Print Chr(13)` is dirty

Comment: `Debug.Print vbCr & Chr(0)` appears to be clean.

Comment: `Debug.Print Chr(0) & vbCr` clean     `Debug.Print Chr(0)` clean

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue: `Debug.Print vbCr` prints either a blank line and nothing, or a blank line and "lls".
It happens randomly, I tried the same fonction with same parameters many times, and each time the printed result is different (either one of the above).

I found an alternative:

```
Debug.Print ""
Debug.Print "My text"
```

This alternative spoils one line of code, but the result is indeed one blank line and "My Text", without any extra random text.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO :-)   Yes, `Debug.Print "" ` is a workaround but more to the point WHY does the `Debug.Print` statements that include `vbCr` fail? Anyway - I hope this helped you preserve your sanity :-)