# C - Code between parameter list and function body

Tags: c, syntax

I have just seen C code in the following manner:

```
void foo(par1, par2)
  int par1;
  short par2;
{
  // some code ...
}
```

What is this called, if you add code between parameter list and function body? Did not find it by googling. What is allowed to do there and what not?

Comment: Does not compile with my `gcc`

Comment: Dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/alternate-c-syntax-for-function-declaration-use-cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you mean to be

```
void foo(par1, par2)
  int par1;
  short par2;
{
   // some code ...
}
```

If this is the snippet then it comes from K&R C and it can be found in older C books and programs. C89 and C99 support this style so that older programs will still compile.