# keyword /definition / return value - "STATUS" in C?

Tags: c, keyword, definition

trying to produce a class that holds minimal code for my debug helpers in c/c++
in my search for sources in `c` for getting `OS` Version, i have discoverd a link where code calls/defines an unknown return value !

```
STATUS
GVver( flags, vout )
i4 flags;
ING_VERSION* vout;

bool
GVosvers( OSVersionString )
char *OSVersionString;


int
GVvista()
```

is that a c Code ? i have tried to understand and follow internal links,
 **within the LINK> [wiki](http://community.actian.com/wiki/Ingres_CL_GV) **

what is this STATUS keyword?

Comment: It could be a typedef to something.  Did you check the documentation?

Comment: This looks very similar to the old-style (K&R) C "function declarations": function arguments are only named, the types are added on separate statements.

Comment: @NathanOliver http://community.actian.com/wiki/Ingres_CL_GV

Comment: this is the source = >
https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwidx8LEzNjIAhXF6xQKHZZHDw0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jonahharris.com%2Fosdb%2Fingres%2Fgpl%2Ftemp%2Fsrc%2Fcl%2Fclf%2Fgv%2Fgvosvers.c&usg=AFQjCNFCmerfZNHooq2UI5RF8GcIqS9cKQ&bvm=bv.105841590,d.d24&cad=rja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302240/keyword-definition-return-value-status-in-c#comment54403174_33302240) mentions, `STATUS` most probably a `typedef` (as `i4`, `ING_VERSION` are, and probably also `bool` at this time). The syntax uses the old style for C function declarations -- known as *K&R style* -- that was already discussed on SO:

- [Alternate C syntax for function declaration use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1630631/2932052)
- [Old style C function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1630631/2932052)

This means, you can read the above as the following in modern C/C++ syntax:

```
STATUS GVver(i4 flags, ING_VERSION* vout);
bool GVosvers(char *OSVersionString);
int GVvista();
```

Comment: tnanks i wasn't sure, now i am ..(: