# declaring a function with this specification

Tags: c, function-prototypes

i recently saw the following code in C which is said to be valid but I'm not sure.

```
    int max(x,y)
    int x,y;
    {
    return (x>y)?x:y;
    }
```

Is this kind of function prototype valid? If so please give some reference to learn more about that.

Comment: [See this also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/alternate-c-syntax-for-function-declaration-use-cases). This question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the old-style "K&R" way of defining functions. The new way is better, so don't write code like this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This code is valid, it's just a pretty old standard.

Nowadays in function declaration the types of arguments are declared right before the names of these arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

But years ago there was another standard where the syntax was different: you had to specify the types like this:

```
int main(argc, argv)
    int argc; char **argv;
```

So, nothing weird here, different standards offer different syntax