# Data declaration in strange C code

Tags: c

I'm looking at the code file found here https://sourceware.org/svn/gcc/tags/var-tracking-assignments-merge-150905-before/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/i386/loop-1.c (I found it under a folder called gcc-torture. Turns out it doesn't torture only just gcc)

My question is this: how many legal data declarations does this snippet have?

```
f1 (a)
     long a;
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      if (--a == -1)
  return i;
    }
  return -1;
}
```

I believe it only has one (`int i;`), but I'm unsure about that strangely placed `long a;`. Does that count as a data declaration? How is it even legal to stuff an apparent data declaration ending in a line terminator inside a function declaration?

Comment: This is an obsolescent and your compiler should complain when compiling as standard code. Configure correctly and enable warnings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate C syntax for function declaration use cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/alternate-c-syntax-for-function-declaration-use-cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's K&R syntax for function definition. It's pretty much obsolete now, but can still be compiled.
These are identical:

```
// K&R
int func(a, b) 
    int a; 
    double b; 
{ 
    return 0; 
}

// ANSI
int func(int a, double b) 
{ 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It does require a warning from a standard compliant or a C99 compiler.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The `int a; double b;` in the K&R syntax are not actually data declarations, but rather arguments. So that little snippet I provided does in fact only have 1 data declaration.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this is a function *definition*, not a declaration.