# Strange placement of struct definition?

Tags: c, syntax

**Duplicate**: [Alternative (K&R) C syntax for function declaration versus prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/alternative-kr-c-syntax-for-function-declaration-versus-prototypes)

I have some homework I need to do (in C) and in this homework we're given some method stubs. I'm not very good in C, but when I looked at the stubs this caught my eye:

```
...
A_output(message)
  struct msg message;
{

}

 A_input(packet)
  struct pkt packet;
{

}
...
```

Namely, the definition of both `msg` and `pkt` *between* the function's name/parameter and definition. Both the `message`and `packet` parameters are to be structs; their respective member declarations are above their first uses, towards the beginning of the .c file:

```
struct msg {
  char data[20];
  };

struct pkt {
   int seqnum;
   int acknum;
   int checksum;
   char payload[20];
    };
```

Is this kind of initialization some sort of C syntax I'm not familiar with or just a typo? I looked around but couldn't find anything like this, nor have I ever seen anything like it in any other language, to split up a function's code like that. The compiler is screaming about invalid function prototyping no matter what I do so something seems amiss...

Comment: Oh, god, it's the 70s all over again. Implicit int and K&R functions.

Comment: "The compiler is screaming about invalid function prototyping" -- Are you sure you're using a C compiler? (Honest question. C++ compilers won't like it.)

Comment: Yes, I've been compiling with GCC.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-kr-vs-ansi

Comment: @hvd even the source of gcc is filled with these kinds of definitions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data declaration in strange C code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531010/data-declaration-in-strange-c-code)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya GCC is a special case. For a long time, GCC went out of its way to ensure it itself could be compiled with pre-ANSI C compilers. After all, if you don't have an ANSI C compiler on a system, and the only ANSI C compiler you can find requires you to have an ANSI C compiler already, you're stuck.

Comment: That's invalid code since 18 years now (and deprecated since 28 years).

Comment: @hvd: So you say the code above is **without a change** valid standard C? Despite the implicit `int`? (not related, but fyi: non-prototype declarators are obsolescence features)

Comment: There is no `struct` (or any other) definition in the function header.

Comment: @Olaf You're right, what I wrote was wrong. The OP asks about the non-prototyped declaration, but uses implicit `int` in the code as well. The former is still valid, the latter is not. I thought you were saying the former is no longer valid, but you didn't say that.

Comment: @hvd: I did not intentionally. Finding out and understanding **what** the actual problem is is a good lesson for beginners.

Comment: @parttimeturtle: C99 is not standard C. But - to be fair - this has not changed in 2011 (I'm just not sure about making K&R parameter _declarations_ an obsolescence feature; maybe you can find out). Said that, you **always** enable compiler warnings. Without ever run into this myself, I'm confident there is an option which covers non-prototype functions declarators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is *very* old code, from before it was standardized in the 1980's.

```
A_output(message)
  struct msg message;
{

}
```

Is a function definition, and `message` is the argument. That's how arguments were defined in "the olden days". Note the missing return type, it implies that the function returns an `int`.

The above definition is equivalent to the following:

```
int A_output(struct msg message)
{

}
```

Comment: ya tell me about it :P poor Dennis is probably spinning in his grave. rep'd and checked, thanks much