# Strange function definition

Tags: c

What do lines 14, 15 mean?

```
sort(a,n)
item *a;
```

I can't understand this. gcc can compile this code, but how can a function look like that?

```
typedef struct {
    char *data;
    int key;} item;
item array[] = {
    {"bill", 3},
    {"neil", 4},
    {"john", 2},
    {"rick", 5},
    {"alex", 1},
};

sort(a,n)
item *a; 
{ 
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int s = 1;

    for(; i < n && s != 0; i++) {
            s = 0;
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    if(a[j].key > a[j+1].key) {
                            item t = a[j];
                            a[j] = a[j+1];
                            a[j+1] = t;
                            s++;
                    }
            }
            n--;
    }
}

main()
{
    sort(array,5);
}
```

Comment: a is a pointer to an item.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/alternate-c-syntax-for-function-declaration-use-cases.