# C Code declares expected variable type after function call

Tags: c, syntax

Currently I am looking at some C code. The code was created to make a .dll for use in visual basic. As I was going through the usual rigor of linking a new c project in visual studio I came across something I haven't seen before. Here is an example:

```
BOOL WINAPI DLLMain(VEGETABLE Carrot, SOILTYPE Dirt, TOOLTYPE Spade)
{
    return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI initialize(myVar)
char* myVar;
{
    myCalc  = do_a_thing(myVar)
    return myCalc
}
```

The declaration of myVar as a char* is really the item in question here. My feeble google attempts haven't shown me anything like what I am seeing here. Is this simply an alternative way to perform type declarations, or is there something more interesting going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: This is prehistoric C, `int WINAPI initialize(myVar) char* myVar;` is the ancient way to write `int WINAPI initialize(char* myVar)`

Comment: As others have said K&R style function definition, however just don't use this, readability & writability are horrible.

Comment: Prehistoric C - the stuff I learned.  What does that make me?

Answer (score 0):

This is the old way, called a [K&R style function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/alternative-kr-c-syntax-for-function-declaration-versus-prototypes).

It's very old, like pre-C89. You don't see or use it in newly written code.

Comment: A quick follow up. Is it reasonable to expect something like visual studio to be ok with the "K&R style?"

Comment: @AdamM. Visual Studio only follows an ancient C standard so it'll probably be more ok with it than more modern compilers.