# Function Prototype - Turning off argument checking

Tags: c, function, function-prototypes

From K&R Book on C, I gathered that if the function prototype declaration omits the arguments (as in `int foo();`) the type and argument checking is turned off and nothing is assumed about the arguments to be compatible with older versions of C and so it doesn't break legacy code.

But the following code throws a compilation error that the prototypes mismatch:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test();
int main(void) {
    test(34.5f);
}

void test(float a) {
    printf("%f\n", a);
}
```

Error:

```
C:\***.c:7:6: error: conflicting types for 'test'
 void test(float a) {
      ^
```

Any explanations?

Comment: gcc adds: `note: an argument type that has a default promotion can't match an empty parameter name list declaration`, so `void test(double a)` works, but `void test(float a)` doesn't. So it seems that "type and argument checking is turned off and nothing is assumed about the arguments" is an oversimplification. You should refer to the C spec to see what the rule actually is.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/alternative-kr-c-syntax-for-function-declaration-versus-prototypes  This question might be considered by some to be a duplicate of that one and wind up closed.

Comment: The compiler expects definition `void test(double a) {}`, as `test(34.5f);` call involves _default argument promotions_, which is the case if given declaration doesn't serve as prototype. One of such promotion is `float ---> double`.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski note that it is still an error even without the call to the function

Answer (score 5):

When a function is declared more than once, all declarations must have *compatible type* (C11 6.2.7/2).  In your code `f` is declared twice - the definition also counts as a declaration.

The definition of "compatible function type" is in C11 6.7.6.3/15:

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types. Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible types. If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and **the type of each parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions.** If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions to the type of the corresponding identifier. (In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)

Therefore `void test()` and `void test(float)` are incompatible. In other words, after seeing `void test();`, any prototype must only use types that are unchanged by the default argument promotions. `float` changes to `double` under those promotions.

I believe this has always been the case since the first C Standard.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function with the parameter of the type `double`.

```
void test(double a) {
    //...
}
```

The problem is in this call

```
test(34.5f);
```

there is used the default argument promotion that converts the argument to the type double.

Comment: The code is still a constraint violation even without the function call

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, **an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration**. So the problem is that `float` would be promoted to `int`, which would then cause a mismatch with the function definition's `float` parameter.

**Declaration:**

```
void test();
```

It's tells the compiler that there exists a function `test` which no parameters and not returns a value.

**Definition:**

```
void test(float a)
```

It's tells the compiler what `test()` actually is and also provides the declaration as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally from all the answers given here and from a little bit of reading, here's what i learned (i posted it as an answer so that it would be helpful to anyone who might come across this question in the future) :

- When I called `test(23.4f)` - The parameter is automatically 'coerced' into double and will be called as  `test(double)` since no prototype is specified (for the arguments, atleast)
- Since any call i make using any arguments will be converted to 'a default promotion', i can't have functions declared as `test(float)` since it will never be used/called. So, `test(double)` works and `test(float)` doesn't.

Correct me if i'm wrong and i'll edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You have told `gcc` to compile `c11` code, not as K&R.

I looked at the `-std=` options, but none of them stand out as being useful.  Perhaps omitting the language standard parameter altogether would help.  Or specify it as `c89`.

In c11, full shaped prototypes are always required.  So the first use gives the function as having parameter= `(void)`.   In pre-c++, that indeed would mean "there might or not be parameters passed".

Comment: “In c11, full shaped prototypes are always required.” Citation?

Comment: nope, tried with c89. Didn't compile using that either.

Comment: @Ryan:  Isn't that one of the chief enhancements of c11?  Or maybe I am thinking of c++11?

Comment: @wallyk: I think you’re thinking of C++11, yeah. It’s described as “obsolescent” by all versions of the C11 spec I can find, but not removed.