# Different way of declaring a function in C

Tags: c

I have come across this C sample code and I have no idea what it means:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int some_int;

int fun (some_int) int* some_int;
{

 return 0;
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Why is `fun` declared that way and what does it even mean? I can't understand the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
int fun (some_int) int* some_int;
{
   ...
}
```

is the old (pre ANSI C) way to write this:

```
int fun (int* some_int)
{
   ...
}
```

Best you forget about this, unless you need to dig into very old source code.

If you found this in a book, throw it away and get a modern C text book. (Actually don't throw it away but keep it as an antique).

BTW the `int some_int;` declaration right after `#include <stdio.h>` is a global variable whose name is totally unrelated to the `some_int` in the `fun` function.

[This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/alternative-kr-c-syntax-for-function-declaration-versus-prototypes) explains it in more details.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at the source code of `CMake`.