# How does the following function definition work?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    extern int fun(float);
    int a=fun(3.5);
    printf("%d",a);
}

int fun(aa)
float aa;
{
    return ((int)aa);
}
```

The code block mentioned above compiles fine on my Visual Studio 8 compiler though output is a junk value. But when I compiled the same code on gcc-4.3.4, I got the following compilation error:

> prog.c:2: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
>   prog.c:8: error: conflicting types for ‘fun’
>   prog.c:3: error: previous declaration of ‘fun’ was here

How will it work when it has following properties:

1. There is a variable declaration before the beginning of function body.
2. The function definition does not have the parameter type of the variable.

Comment: This is old C function declaration. Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581586/old-style-c-function-declaration

Comment: I see nothing wrong in this Q, Why is this being voted for closure as not constructive? There is a definite substance to the Q that is OP is asking,if you do not understand the Q, You are not competent to decide if it is not constructive or not,so refrain from doing so.This at best could be a duplicate but none of the close votes mark it as so.

Comment: I agree with @als here, seems like a reasonable question with a nice detailed accepted answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this function definition work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236384/how-does-this-function-definition-work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function is written in K&R style, and your prototype for it is incorrect.  In fact, there are other problems too...

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    extern int fun(float);
    int a=fun(3.5);
    printf("%d",a);
}

int fun(aa)
float aa;
{
    return ((int)aa);
}
```

The return type of `main()` is `int`, at least in Standard C.  Your print statement should include a newline.

Your prototype would be OK if the function `fun()` were written with a prototype:

```
int fun(float aa) { ... }
```

However, the function is written in K&R style, and therefore the function expects to be passed a `double` which it will convert to `float`:

```
int fun(double aa_arg) { float aa = aa_arg; ... }
```

In K&R C, all `float` values were passed as `double`.  This is why you are getting garbage; you are lying (probably unwittingly) to your compiler, and it is getting its own back by doing GIGO on you.

FWIW: GCC 4.6.1 refuses to compile your code (even without any warning settings).  It complains:

```
f1.c: In function ‘main’:
f1.c:2: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
f1.c: At top level:
f1.c:9: error: conflicting types for ‘fun’
f1.c:3: error: previous declaration of ‘fun’ was here
```

You can fix this in a number of different ways:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    extern int fun(float);
    int a = fun(3.5);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return(0);
}

int fun(float aa)
{
    return ((int)aa);
}
```

Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    extern int fun(double);
    int a = fun(3.5);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return(0);
}

int fun(double aa)
{
    return ((int)aa);
}
```

Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    extern int fun(double);
    int a = fun(3.5);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return(0);
}

int fun(aa)
double aa;
{
    return ((int)aa);
}
```

Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    extern int fun(double);
    int a = fun(3.5);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return(0);
}

int fun(aa)
float aa;
{
    return ((int)aa);
}
```

Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    extern int fun();
    int a = fun(3.5);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return(0);
}

int fun(aa)
float aa;
{
    return ((int)aa);
}
```

I believe these are all correct and they all should compile without warnings (unless you ask the compiler to complain about old style (K&R) function definitions, etc).

With GCC set to rather fussy, I get the warnings:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition f2.c -o f2  
f2.c:12: warning: no previous prototype for ‘fun’
/usr/bin/gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition f3.c -o f3  
f3.c:12: warning: no previous prototype for ‘fun’
/usr/bin/gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition f4.c -o f4  
f4.c:12: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
f4.c: In function ‘fun’:
f4.c:13: warning: old-style function definition
/usr/bin/gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition f5.c -o f5  
f5.c:12: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
f5.c: In function ‘fun’:
f5.c:13: warning: old-style function definition
/usr/bin/gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition f6.c -o f6  
f6.c: In function ‘main’:
f6.c:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
f6.c: At top level:
f6.c:12: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
f6.c: In function ‘fun’:
f6.c:13: warning: old-style function definition
```

Comment: Hi this is what I understood - so in K&R C we cant declare a function to receive float datatype(or short,char in integer family)as they are promoted to double and int, to overcome this we are using ANSI C standard where we can expect a float as parameter:int fun(float aa).Please correct me if I am wrong.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is the **[K & R style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style)** of function definition. It is non standard compliant and hence the compiler error in gcc(which is used by Ideone).

It works for you in visual studio because visual studio allows you to change the default coding style.