# What is difference between ANSI C and C Programming Language?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner, so please let me know the difference between ANSI C and the C programming Language.

Comment: If you're a beginner, this is unimportant historical information you should completely ignore. It will only distract you.

Comment: You might like to read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#History Related also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22500/694576

Comment: You can read the [C89 rationale](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/title.html), which explains, _why_ certain things were changed (and by that tells you _what_ was changed). Probably the most important changes: function prototypes (look for old-style or K&R function declarations and definitions if you're interested) and the preprocessor (which varied a lot between different implementations).

Answer (score 18):

ANSI is a US standards body that released the first standard specification for C in 1989.  The standard was adopted by ISO in 1990 and ISO are now the standards body for the language - not ANSI.

ANSI C merely refers to a particular standard for the C Programming Language - i.e. there is no difference, they refer to the same thing. However there have been several standards and de-facto standards for C:

- K&R C - as defined by the first edition of *The C Programming Language* by Brian Kernhigan and Dennis Ritchie, published in 1978.
- ANSI C - 1989 (also known as C89).  Described (but no longer *defined*) by K&R 2nd Ed.
- ISO C 1990 (C90 - more-or-less identical to C89, but in an ISO document).
- ISO C 1999 (C99)
- ISO C 2011 (C11)

Comment: While a lot of people think of ANSI C as C89, C11 has also been ratified by ANSI and technically ANSI C is actually C11.

Comment: @ouah : Which only serves to make the term *ANSI C* even more ambiguous and best avoided. Besides it is not quite true; C90 was *ratified* by ANSI, C99 and C11 were *adopted*. The ISO C standards committee is an international body - it would be rather parochial to claim it as "American".  It is also adopted by by the [*British Standards Institute*](http://tinyurl.com/plowzf3), but no one would refer to it as *BSI C*!  In a more practical sense the [`-ansi` switch in GCC](http://tinyurl.com/po2xt3n) enforces C90.

Comment: Note that since writing those there is a ISO C17 and a C2x in development - I am not going to maintain this answer, - you get the point.