# Can some one describe the following function body which I found in the mallo.c of GNU llibc?

Tags: c, function, malloc

```
__ptr_t
_malloc (size)
     __malloc_size_t size;
{
  return malloc (size);
}
```

As far as I know of the function declaration it looks as follows :

```
<return-type> <function-name>(<data-type> <var-name>){

// Code..
}
```

But above function looks different.

Comment: Those are K&R-style parameters. You may find [**this interesting**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500/what-are-the-major-differences-between-ansi-c-and-kr-c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is old K&R style.

```
/* ISO style */
int fn(int i, char j)
{
}
```

---

```
/* Pre standard K&R style */
int fn(i, j)  /* return type if int is optional, if omitted defaults to int */
int i;        /* this line if argument type is int is optional */
char j;
{
}
```

[Live Example here](http://ideone.com/GsWYGh)

Answer (score 2):

`__ptr_t` - return type

`_malloc` - function name

`size` - name of the argument

`__malloc_size_t` type of the argument named size

this is old legacy syntax, check out more [here](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-C.html)

> To support pre-standard C, instead of writing function definitions in
>   standard prototype form,
>
> int foo (int x, int y) … write the definition in pre-standard style
>   like this,
>
> int foo (x, y)
>        int x, y;

Answer (score 2):

This is an old declaration style from very early C, known as the "K&R" style, after Kernighan and Ritchie, originators of the language.  Inside the brackets of the function's parameter list, you just declare the `<var-name>`s of the arguments; then after the brackets but before the opening curly brace of the function body you place full declarations of the `<var-name>`s with their `<data-type>`s, as if you were declaring local variables.