# What does a line after function declaration but outside function itself

Tags: c

What does it mean if something like the two lines after the main function declaration appears in C code?

```
int main(argc,argv)
  int argc;
  char *argv[];
{
  // main function body
}
```

I've never seen anything like this before.  The code works just fine, but I'm curious to know what this means.  Thanks!

Comment: that's obsolete [K&R syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092006/function-declaration-kr-vs-ansi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the original (read: ancient) style of declaring argument parameters in K&R C. In ANSI C standards, the form you're likely familiar with has been the standard.

See also: [What are the major differences between ANSI C and K&R C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500/what-are-the-major-differences-between-ansi-c-and-kr-c)

Answer (score 1):

It is just one other way of declaring the datatype of arguments of that particular function.

Comment: No, it's actually not "just one other way of declaring the datatype of arguments".  It's a way of defining the arguments the function receives - but only after those arguments have undergone default argument promotion.

Comment: Yes. You are right! So can I say - the default argument promotion is used when we are not sure of the datatype of receiving arguments.

Comment: While it is another way of declaring function arguments, it's a way that's not compatible at all with newer/ANSI/ISO C declarations and definitions.  I just wanted to point that out clearly so no one would think they could do something like mix new-style function declarations/prototypes with old K&R style function definitions.

Answer (score 1):

That's ["K&R" C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language#History).  It's way out of date.

Don't use it, even if your compiler supports it.  Arguments passed to a function defined in that manner will have undergone argument promotion so that every argument has the same size (via the same mechanism that varargs are promoted in up-to-date C code).

Such code also does not support function declarations/prototypes.  And never try to "improve" such code by creating function prototypes - you'll break the argument promotion that the function is expecting.