# Unable to recognise the syntax for C programming language, as given in book

Tags: c

The book titled: Compiler Design in C, by Allen Holub; page 41 [image] has weird syntax, with function definitions, and variable declarations are given inside no opening and closing braces.

Second, unable to understand how the code line #103 works:

```
if( (fd =!name? STDIN: (*Openp) (name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY)) != -1)
```

i.e., the function call:

```
(*Openp) (name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY)
```

The function 'Openp' is given on page 40:[image]in line #62.
Also, the page 39 is attached too, for ease in reference.
[image]

The book is available for free by the author [here](https://holub.com/goodies/compiler/compilerDesignInC.pdf).

Tried to check into the preface of the book, and the another book by the author, titled: The C Companion.

But, this syntax is not discussed anywhere.

Comment: please don't post screenshots of text/code. Copy paste or write the relevant code into the question.

Comment: ...`if( (fd =!name? STDIN: (*Openp) (name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY)) != -1)` - I hope this is an example of how not to write code...

Comment: @bolov the images appear to be scans of paper, so probably fair, but could surely have been cropped to the content!

Comment: There is a reason the book is free. It is obsolete. That is pre-ANSI (C89) K&R 1st edition C syntax. Obsolete since 1989.  Unfortunate timing on the author's part, published in 1990, he was either unaware or chose backward compatibility for existing compilers.  Though compiler support for ANSI C was already largely in place before publication of the standard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500/what-are-the-major-differences-between-ansi-c-and-kr-c

Comment: You have two separate questions here, the first largely ignored in the current answers.  You should post separate questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> page 41 *[...]* has weird syntax, with function definitions, and variable declarations are given inside no opening and closing braces.

At the time that book was published (1990), that syntax was "*traditional*" not "*weird*".  It is the syntax defined in *The C Programming Language* ed.1 by Kernighan & Richie (K&R).  Prior to publication of the ANSI standard for C in 1989, that book was the *de facto* standard for C.  No doubt the preparation of this book predated the publication of C89, and is just unfortunate timing for the publisher that it was obsolete at time of publication.  Although given that Prentice Hall also published K&R 2nd. ed, and Brian Kernighan edited this book - they would surely have been aware?  Moreover the preface claims that all the code is ANSI C and that Microsoft C 5.1 was used.  I recall that ANSI C was introduced at MS C v6 in 1989, but I could be wrong. 5.1 was released in 1988 - pre-ANSI finalisation.  They were probably still arguing about it in the committee ;-). Version 3.0 (1984) was the first to claim ANSI compatibility, but it would have been speculative and only against an early draft at that time. So charitably perhaps we can excuse the confusion due to the state of flux the language was in at that time.

Clearly no one was going to obsolete the huge existing code body, so a pragmatic compiler would accept either syntax - probably by default.  Certainly Microsoft were more concerned with customers being able to build their existing code than strict enforcement of new standards.

That said the subject of the book is not specifically C language, but rather compiler implementation.  Perhaps it still has relevant content regarding compiler implementation, but you may need to adapt the code examples.

In this case:

[image]

is equivalent to ANSI/ISO C:

```c
void ii_io( int(*open_funct)(), 
            int(*close_funct)(),
            int(*read_funct)() )
{
    ...
```

In K&R ed.1 C the argument list in parentheses defines only the argument *names*, and the *types* are defined between that and the opening brace of the function.  The function pointer syntax perhaps makes that less clear than a simpler function interface such as:

```c
int fn( arg1 ) int arg1 { return arg1 ; }
```

being equivalent to:

```c
int fn( int arg1 ) { return arg1 ; }
```

Your compiler is likely to issue a warning if you attempt to compile K&R ed.1  code, it may even reject it, and you will have to set the C standard in use or use an old compiler to use the code directly.

With respect to:

```c
if( (fd =!name? STDIN: (*Openp) (name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY)) != -1)
```

That remains valid code in ISO C, so is really a separate question.  `Openp` is some global function pointer that is assigned `open_funct` at line 76.  The Boolean expression `!name` will be `true` if `name` is a NULL pointer, in which case the file descriptor `fd` takes `STDIN` (a macro the file descriptor of the `stdin` stream which is zero (macro defined on page 39). `STDIN` is not defined in the standard library, but POSIX defined `STDIN_FILENO` (unistd.h).

If `name` is not null, then `fd` is assigned the return value of the function `Openp` (and `open_funct`) refers to.  Implicitly a function that opens the file with the name `name`.

There are a couple of things to note about the `Openp` call:

1. First the explicit de-reference is optional - certainly in modern C, not sure about K&R C.  So `Openp(name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY)` is also valid.
2. The type of `open_funct` and `Openp` - i.e. `int(*)()` - is a function with an undefined number for parameters so can be a pointer to any function returning an `int` with any number of parameters of any type. There is no potential therefore for checking that the function provided by `open_funct` has the correct *signature*.  Extra parameters will be ignored, and types may mismatch.  The POSIX `open()` is a variadic function allowing two versions with and without a `mode` argument (a kind of "fake" function overloading).  The lack of argument definition allows that but you might replace such definitions with the more rigorous: `int (*fn)(char*, int, ...)` to match the POSIX `open()` signature, which is likely the intention here.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( (fd =!name? STDIN: (*Openp) (name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY)) != -1)
```

We can write this as:

```
if ( (fd = (!name ? STDIN : (*Openp) (name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY))) != 1)
```

It assigns the file descriptor `STDIN` — which I believe might be a symbolic name for `STDIN_FILENO` or so — or the file descriptor returned by the call to the function pointed to by `Openp`, depending on whether `name` evaluates to true or false.

It can be rewritten as:

```
fd = !name ? STDIN : (*Openp) (name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY); 

if (fd == -1) {
    /* Handle error here. */
}
```

Or more verbosely as:

```
if (!name) {
    fd = STDIN;
} else {
    fd = (*Openp) (name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY); 
}

if (fd == -1) {
    /* Handle error here. */
}
```

Note that the two calls:

```
(*Openp) (name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY);
```

and

```
Openp(name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY);
```

are equivalent. See: [How do function pointers work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840501/20017547)

Answer (score 0):

Can be read in such a way:

```
typedef int(*Openp)(const char*, int, ... );

if(name == 0)
{
    fd = STDIN;
}
else
{
    fd = (*Openp) (name, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY);
}
if( fd != -1)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Instead of `typedef int(*Openp)(int);`, better as `typedef int(*Openp)(const char *, int);` as the function pointer `Openp` takes 2 arguments.

Comment: What @chux-ReinstateMonica  said; but to match the signature of POSIX `open()` which is likley the intention :   `typedef int(*Openp)(const char *, int, ... ) ;`.  A single `int` is just incorrect - `name` is  `char*`, and you pass `char*, int`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks. Edited.

Comment: ... although it remains valid in C (not C++) to have an empty "undefined" parameter list.  In C++ it means the same as `(void)`, - no parameters, while in C it means undefined number and type of arguments.